# How to implement responsive offcanvas with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to create an admin dashboard with a responsive sidebar. My goal is to have a fixed sidebar with screen larger than .md (bootstrap class) and an offcanvas sidebar with screens less than .md.
I'm trying to use offcanvas component of ng-bootstrap library in order to use same component for both situations. Do someone have an example of code that works in this way? Tried to search through youtube and google but nothing

I tried to use [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/#responsive), but didn't work. Probably there is the need to import some bootstrap's JS file. But I want to use ng-bootstrap offcanvas component